# How to prevent grid overflow?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm very new to css grid. I saw some similar questions but i dint quiet get it. I m not able to wrap my head around this concept so well. How can i prevent components from overflowing from a grid?

The image i have uploaded is of the section which has the classname of `profile-widget-wrapper`. I have defined `grid-row:2/4`. But it is overflowing the grid definition. How can i fix this? Any help is appreciated. Learning CSS Grid. Thank you.

[image]

```css
.wrapper{  //main wrapper
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr;
 grid-template-rows: 100px 300px 100px;
}
.profile-widget-wrapper{    //section that is overflowing
    grid-row:2/4;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <section class="profile-widget-wrapper">
    <div class="profile-widget">
      <h5 class="title">PROFILE WIDGET</h5>
      <ul class="widget-optns">
         <li class="active">
           <h5>PROFILE OVERVIEW</h5>
         </li>
         <li class="count">
           <h5>FRIENDS</h5>
           <span class="friend-count">383</span>
          </li>
         <li class="count">
           <h5>GAMES OWNED</h5>
           <span class="games-owned-count">10</span> 
          </li>
         <li>
           <h5>STEAM QUICK LINKS</i></h5>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  </section>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're encountering default margins and padding.

Also, you're creating a grid area across two rows (`2/4`). Try just one (`2/3`).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 300px 100px;
}

.profile-widget-wrapper {
  /* grid-row: 2/4; */ /* spans two rows */
  grid-row: 2 / 3;     /* spans one row */
}

/* remove default style marker, padding and/or margin */
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* horizontal alignment of content */
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline; /* to work around h5 margins */
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="profile-widget-wrapper">
    <div class="profile-widget">
      <h5 class="title">PROFILE WIDGET</h5>
      <ul class="widget-optns">
        <li class="active">
          <h5>PROFILE OVERVIEW</h5>
        </li>
        <li class="count">
          <h5>FRIENDS</h5>
          <span class="friend-count">383</span>
        </li>
        <li class="count">
          <h5>GAMES OWNED</h5>
          <span class="games-owned-count">10</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h5>STEAM QUICK LINKS</h5>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to span from 2/4 .But if u observe closely in the image it is spanning across 4 also.But any way ur answer fixed my problem.Thank you so much for helping